# How to find and replace in loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, replace, find

I have done some searching on here and cannot find an exact answer to figure out this question. I currently have dynamic divs with select elements added to a form. The input names are placed as an array, these divs can also be removed dynamically. I need to figure out a way that when the user removes this div, the divs and inputs below get renamed. I hope that made sense. Here is an example of what happens after a user deletes a div containing the input fields:

```
<div class="rooms" id="row1">
  <input type="text" name="room[1][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[1][children]">
</div>
<div class="rooms" id="row3">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][children]">
</div>
```

I need to be able to loop through the .rooms divs and find and replace the numeric element on the name property of the input. So `room[3][adults]` needs to be changed to `room[2][adults]`. There can be up to eight divs at a time when the loop is running. Here is what I had as an idea, but I can't figure out how to replace that one number in between.

```
var i = 1;
$(".rooms").each(function () {
  var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
  var numToFind = thisId.substr(thisId.length - 1);
  $("#"+thisId).find("select[name='room["+numToFind+"][adults]']").replace( 'room["+numToFind+"][adults]','room["+i+"][adults]');
  $("#"+thisId).find("select[name='room["+numToFind+"][children]']").replace( 'room["+numToFind+"][children]','room["+i+"][children]');
  i = i + 1;
});
```

So this is pretty much all I could think of, any help at accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have concatenation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues

- `find()` returns a jQuery object which does not have `replace()` method
- Just using `replace` is not enough, you need to get the name, replace the content and set it back

You can use  a simple iteration an replace like

```js
var i = 1;
$(".rooms").each(function() {
  $(this).find('input[name^=room]').attr('name', function(idx, name) {
    return name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + i + ']');
  });
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rooms" id="row1">
  <input type="text" name="room[1][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[1][children]">
</div>
<div class="rooms" id="row3">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][children]">
</div>
<div class="rooms" id="row3">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][children]">
</div>
<div class="rooms" id="row3">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][adults]">
  <input type="text" name="room[3][children]">
</div>
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution! Thank you, after programming for 12 hours straight, brain becomes mush lol.